# How can I get the Free Pascal Compiler xcode template to work with xcode 4

Tags: templates, xcode4, fpc

I'd love to start using Pascal again on the mac and fpc 2.4.2 comes with a template for xcode. However, that template was designed for an earlier version of xcode and and after I install it, I still don't see any option to use fpc in a new xcode project.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0):

Search the recent archives from the mac-pascal list (which is nowadays mostly about FPC):

http://lists.sonic.net/mailman/listinfo/mac-pascal

Comment: The archive is not visible to non-members of the mailing list.

Comment: Pasting the relevant content here would be better than making people join a mailing list to be able to search its archives.

Comment: That maillist is the main Mac Pascal resource. Anybody serious about FPC on Mac should subscribe to it. I monitor it for other purposes, since I use Lazarus, not XCode, so can't really judge which pieces small enough are worth quoting, and which ones are not (even if just due to OS X, xcode and fpc versioning)

Answer (score 0):

Phil Hess wrote some templates that work in XCode 4 which used to be at this link:

http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/Xcode4PascalTemplates_20110905.zip

Unfortunately me.com is gone (Apple nuked it), so when I get in touch with Phil Hess, and find where they live now, I'll update this answer with new information.

Answer (score 0):

Latest Xcode template is available here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28343282/ObjP/index.html. Though it doesn't support latest Xcode.